# Can oplog be put in a different disk partition?

Tags: replication, mongodb

I'm just curious if this is possible. Coming from mysql, the log_bin can be put on a different disk.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, add `storage.directoryPerDB: true` to your configuration:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  directoryPerDB: true
```

Then you can put a symbolic link at `/var/lib/mongo/local` pointing to your disk